# How to filter a table by checkbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, checkbox

I'm creating a table from a XML file. The table has three columns (name, date, secret) and dynamic rows. I have created a checkbox on the header of the secret column (third column). When I click on the checkbox it should only show the one row with the oldest date of those who has the same "secret" and the same "name". If two rows has two identical secrets, but two different names, then both rows should be shown. The main part in the XSLT file is just the checkbox. I am not sure if I really need a onchange="identicalSecrets()" for the xslt code.

See code below for javascript. It doesn't work so I'm pretty sure that I have many mistakes on javascript code.

XSLT or HTML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head><title>Shared Secrets</title></head>

<body>
    <h1>Shared Secrets</h1>
<table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:red"></col>
            <col width="165"></col>
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:grey">
            <th>plane
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="filterReports()">
                     <option selected="selected">All</option>
                     <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane">
                        <option>
                         <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </option>
                     </xsl:for-each>                    
                </select>                   
            </th>   
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Secret
                <input type="checkbox" id="identicalSecrets" onchange="identicalSecrets()"></input>
                <label for="identicalSecrets">hide identical secrets</label>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../Name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="secret"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../../filterReports.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src=/../../identicalSecrets.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Main part on the code above:

```
<th>Secret
    <input type="checkbox" id="identicalSecrets" onchange="identicalSecrets()"></input>
    <label for="identicalSecrets">hide identical secrets</label>
</th>
```

Javascript code:

```
function identicalSecrets() {
    let checkBox, filter, rows, cells, secret;
    checkBox=document.getElementById('identicalSecrets');
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    filter = checkBox.value;
    for (let row of rows) {
        cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        secret = cells[2];
        if (filter == true) {
            if (secret === row[-1].getElementsbyTagName("td")[2] && secret ===  row[-1].getElementsbyTagName("td")[0]) { // If the actual secret is equal to the secret in the last row and the modelranges are equal then hide these rows.
                row.style.display = "none"; // hide this row
            }
            else { // if secret or modelrange are not equal
                row.style.display = ""; // show this row
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I expect that when I click the checkbox, all rows with equal first column and third column will disappear except the row with the oldest date (second column).

Comment: Please post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just a note for now: some of your HTML seems invalid, such as `input` tags not self-closed.

Comment: Also note, the javascript tag for "/../../identicalSecrets.js" is missing the opening quote for the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your javascript...

- You have referenced a variable called `table`, but have not defined it.
- Doing `row[-1]` is not valid because `row` is not an array (`rows` is), and -1 isn't a valid index as arrays are 0-based. You should really set up a variable (called `index`) to keep a count of the row indexes, then you can do `rows[index - 1]` to get the previous row
- You only want to start checking the rows on the third row (as the first row is the header row, and the second row will have no previous data row to check)
- You are comparing the `secret` value with both the first and third columns. But you should be checking the name for the first column
- Javascript functions are case-sensitive, so `getElementsbyTagName` will not work due to the lower-case "by"
- You should really use "innerText" to get the text value of the cell, as you want to compare the text, not the cell object itself.

So, putting it all together, your javascript should probably look like this:

```
function identicalSecrets() {
    let table, checkBox, filter, rows, cells, secret, name;
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    checkBox=document.getElementById('identicalSecrets');
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    filter = checkBox.checked;
    let index = 0;
    for (let row of rows) {
        if (index > 1) {
            cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
            name = cells[0].innerText;
            secret = cells[2].innerText;
            if (filter == true) {
                if (name === rows[index - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText && secret === rows[index - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerText) {
                    row.style.display = "none"; // hide this row
                }
                else { // if secret or modelrange are not equal
                    row.style.display = "table-row"; // show this row
                }
            }
            else {
                row.style.display = "table-row"; // show this row
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWi

Comment: I think it might be better to ask a whole new question for that. Thanks